# Access query to include all records even if 1 field has missing data

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can I get MS Access 2010 to include data in a query if 1 field has missing data.

IE: I have a `sn` column in `tblPropertydevices` and a `sn` column in `tblBrentwoodID` that is imported from another source. If there is a typo in the imported data `sn` column, the entire report is not printed.

I would like for the report to print all reports & ignore the missing data in the one column. I have tried "<>"" Or is null" in the criteria for that column wth no results.

The query pulls data from several tables and prints test reports based on date tested and tech#. That is the only 2 fields that absolutely have to match.

Comment: Please include the SQL. I suspect you need a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

All you have to do is click on the relationship line in the query and select the 2nd radio button to include all records from the firs table.

Too easy
Toby